# Ubuntu 16.04 pip seems broken

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I was installing some packages, after that pip doesn't work anymore. Even if I try some command such as: sudo pip show requets I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 6, in <module>
    import compileall
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/futures-3.1.1-py3.5.egg/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/futures-3.1.1-py3.5.egg/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 381
    raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks anyways!

Comment: What packages did you install? Is this the first time you see this specific error?

Comment: have you updated the system python?

Comment: @mata I was trying to install polyglot, seems like there's some issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try reinstalling `pip` if nothing else is working for you. Execute the following:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`

`sudo apt-get purge python-pip`

`wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py`

`sudo python get-pip.py`

That should work. After doing that, run `pip --version` and please post the results.

Comment: I executed these commands and I still getting the same error, pip --version also gives me the error that I posted.

Comment: @PedroLima Can you tell me what Python version you're using? `python --version`.

Comment: When I try to run  'sudo python get-pip.py' I get this error. You're using an outdated location for the get-pip.py script, please use the one available from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: I using python 2.7.12

Comment: Can you execute `pip install Django` and let me know what you see? I just want to make sure it's the same error as the one you posted above.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove python-pip`, then
`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`, then
`sudo easy_install -U pip`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have installed the [futures](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures/3.1.1) package on python3.5.

That is a python2 only backport of a python3.2+ package.
You need to delete `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/futures-3.1.1-py3.5.egg` then it should work again.
You don't need that package on python3.5, it is already included in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pip is broken, can you check pip version using `pip --version` and maybe upgrading pip to latest version might solve your problem, just try 
`sudo pip install --upgrade pip` , now check pip version and if it still shows the old version try to recreate the simlink using `ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/`

Comment: I can't run these commands, no matter what I try do do with pip I get that error.

Comment: Thanks, It was the futures module on python3.5 folder.